# Esqueleto's types in `leftJoin` seem inconsistent with the documentation

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I'm trying to do a `leftJoin` using the following query:

```
      select $ do
        (event :& _ :& tags) <- from
            $ table @EventRow `leftJoin` table @EventTagRow
            `on` ( \(event :& links) ->
                     event ^. EventRowId ==. links ?. EventTagRowEventId
                 )
              `leftJoin` table @TagRow
            `on` ( \(_ :& link :& tag) ->
                     tag ?. TagRowId ==. link ?. EventTagRowTagId
                 )
        where_ (event ^. EventRowTitle ==. val "one")
        pure tags
```

The problem I have is that the line `event ^. EventRowId ==. links ?. EventTagRowEventId` complains that `EventRowId` gives an ID type, but `==.` wants `Maybe <id type>`. This makes sense, when I look at the definitions of `?.` and `==.` they are:

```
(?.) :: (PersistEntity val, PersistField typ) => SqlExpr (Maybe (Entity val)) -> EntityField val typ -> SqlExpr (Value (Maybe typ)) 
(==.) :: PersistField typ => SqlExpr (Value typ) -> SqlExpr (Value typ) -> SqlExpr (Value Bool)
```

Which would imply that the LHS and RHS *both* have to be maybe. Yet the docs for `Database.Esqueleto.Experimental` give the following example (see "Example 2: Select with join" in [the section "A New Syntax"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-3.5.9.0/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Experimental.html#g:3)):

```
select $ do
(people :& blogPosts) <-
    from $ table @Person
    `leftJoin` table @BlogPost
    `on` (\(people :& blogPosts) ->
            people ^. PersonId ==. blogPosts ?. BlogPostAuthorId)
where_ (people ^. PersonAge >. val 18)
pure (people, blogPosts)
```

Which implies that `==.` can take a `SqlExpr (Value typ) -> SqlExpr (Maybe (Value typ))`. Is the documentation wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't tried to reproduce the problem, and it's been a long time sice I last used Esqueleto, but anyway, a guess: does it work if you change `tag ?. TagRowId` to `tag ^. TagRowId` in your second left join? As far as that join is concerned, the tag is supposed to exist.

Comment: @duplode no it doesn't because `leftJoin` produces `Maybe (Entity val)`s rather than `Entity val`s. The thing I'm most concerned by is that the Esqueleto documentation just seems inconsistent...

Comment: The documentation bug has now been fixed in Esqueleto 3.5.9.1. Thanks for bringing it into light!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the left hand side of the first `on` clause in [`just`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-3.5.9.0/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Experimental.html#v:just), which lifts values into `Maybe`, fixes the type error:

```
        `on` ( \(event :& links) ->
                 just (event ^. EventRowId) ==. links ?. EventTagRowEventId
             )
```

There was indeed a documentation bug (see [Esqueleto issue #307](https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto/issues/307)) which has since been fixed in Esqueleto 3.5.9.1.

Below is a runnable demo of the fixed code:

```
{- cabal:
build-depends: base >= 4.16
            , persistent
            , persistent-sqlite
            , esqueleto >= 3.5.8
            , text
-}
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Database.Persist.Sqlite (runSqlite)
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Esqueleto.Experimental
import Data.Text (Text)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
EventRow
  title Text
  deriving Show
EventTagRow
  eventId EventRowId
  tagId TagRowId
  deriving Show
TagRow
  deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
  runMigration migrateAll

  event1 <- insert $ EventRow "one"
  event2 <- insert $ EventRow "two"
  event3 <- insert $ EventRow "three"

  tag1 <- insert $ TagRow
  tag2 <- insert $ TagRow

  insert $ EventTagRow event1 tag1
  insert $ EventTagRow event3 tag2

  tags <- select $ do
    (event :& _ :& tags) <- from
        $ table @EventRow `leftJoin` table @EventTagRow
        `on` ( \(event :& links) ->
                 just (event ^. EventRowId) ==. links ?. EventTagRowEventId
             )
          `leftJoin` table @TagRow
        `on` ( \(_ :& link :& tag) ->
                 tag ?. TagRowId ==. link ?. EventTagRowTagId
             )
    where_ (event ^. EventRowTitle ==. val "one")
    pure tags
  liftIO $ do
    putStrLn "\nTesting...\n"
    print tags
```